# How do I get the contents of a selected row from a YUI datatable?

Tags: yui

I'm trying to get the contents of a cell in a row in a YUI datatable.

I can use `myDataTable.getSelectRows()[0]` to get the first selected row. However, how do I get the contents of the first cell in that row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like getSelectRows() returns an array of record IDs.  You can retrieve the corresponding record using getRecord().  Once you have a record, use getData() to retrieve the value of the field you are interested in.

```
var recordID = myDataTable.getSelectRows()[0],
    record = myDataTable.getRecord(recordID);
console.log(record.getData("myField"));
```

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html#method_getRecord
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Record.html#method_getData

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have the answer for you assuming you have not already found it yourself.

I have the same kind of page with a datatable and a textarea field, when you select a row in the datatable calls the same page displays further detail from the selected row in the textarea field and retains selection of the selected row.

1: To do this I apply the following example MySQL query called AllMyBroadcasts...

SELECT @rownum :=@rownum + 1 RowNumber, p.*
FROM tblBroadcasts p, (SELECT @rownum := 0)r
ORDER BY Date DESC

the tblBroadcasts table has fields : Date, Narrative, ID

2: I then provide the following to the table row of my YUI Datatable within HTML hyperlink tags.

href="MyPage.php?SelectedBroadcastID=' .$row_Broadcasts['ID'].'&RowNumber=' .($row_Broadcasts['RowNumber'] -1 )

3: When the href is clicked MyPage reload with additional parameters SelectedBroadcastID and RowNumber the SelectedBroadcastID I use in a second query against tblBroadcasts called MySlectedBroadcast which a simple query on outputting all fields where the ID = SelectedbordcastID. I then  to my field to  display the narrative of my selected row in my textarea field.

The second paramater I do the following with.

$SelectedRowID = 0;
if( isset($_GET['RowNumber'])) {
$SelectedRowID = $_GET['RowNumber'];
}

Above I placed just after code covering my two queries.

4: Then finally to get the datatable to select the row of the selected row I include the following to the var yuidatdatable section of the datatable script...

yuidatatable1.select(yuidatatable1.getRow());

The -1 value referred to step 2 serves as a work around to fact that yuidatatable works on a 0 base and the MySQL referred to in step 1 on a 1 base.

There you go !

Perhaps there is a better why using get from within YUIDatatable scripting, be nice to know if so. That said this work fine for me and perhaps if you have not found an answer I hope this helps.